# Unable to stop BufferReader from taking input in console

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program which takes first argument as the (size + 1) of list that is, the number of elements. To keep the elements and index the same, I have added a false value at index 0 of the list. When the program runs it takes three inputs from the user (which is what I want) and terminates.

But when I uncomment the rest of the code, which is actually required, the program keeps on accepting input and won't terminate whatever I try to do, except when I press terminate button.

Please someone explain me why so?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FastReader {

    BufferedReader br;
    StringTokenizer st;

    public FastReader() {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    String next() {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    long nextLong() {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    double nextDouble() {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    String nextLine() {
        String str = "";
        try {
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    void close() {
        try {
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FastReader s = new FastReader();
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int k = s.nextInt();
    int x = s.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.add(0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        p.add(i, i);
    }
    //for(int i=x; p.size()>2; i=(1+1)%p.size()){
    //  int cp= i;
    //  int tk= cp%k;
    //  for(int j = cp+1; j<=cp+tk; j++){
    //      p.remove((Object)j);
    //  }
    //}
    //System.out.print(p.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the commented code is expected to do? What is the meaning of the variables (`K`, `X`, `cp`, `tk`)? What are you trying to achieve? To me it seems that you programmed an endless loop (i.e., `p.size()` is always greater than `1`)

Comment: i am removing element on some logic(included in commented code) one by one until 2 elements are left....first element being that false value and the other being the second last element which i actually want!
the loop wont be infinite as i m removing elements until the list size is 2(as far as i know)....

Comment: `(1+1)`... Isn't that always 2?

Comment: @MCEmperor this is one of the problems with the logic

Comment: Your problem is not the BufferedReader - your problem is with the logic in the second part. You could replace `int N = s.nextInt(); int K = s.nextInt(); int X = s.nextInt();` with `int N = 5; int K = 3; int X = 2;` and you would still have the same problem.

Comment: I find your `for` loop very peculiar. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here: `for (int i = x; p.size() > 2; i = (1 + 1) % p.size())`?

Comment: Thomas you are right...just came to know that thing...could you please tell why is that so even if i remove code for taking input from console , the console continues to accept input. how is it possible?

Comment: The JVM accepts any characters that you type into the console and stores them for you to retrieve by reading from `System.in`. This does however not mean that your program is waiting for input - your program is running within the second for loop (and the program would finish when the second for loop finishes)

Comment: So you mean it isnt neccessary to use scanner or buffer class for JVM to accept input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` condition is the issue. You're stuck in an infinite loop. This has nothing to do from reading input data.

```
for(int i=x; p.size()>2; i=(1+1)%p.size()){
```

will first do `i = x`, then if `p.size()>2` `i` will be equal to `(1+1)%p.size()`, which is `2`. And the condition of your for loop is forever true: at some point your list `p` will contain `[0, 1, 2]` and no element greater than or equal to `2+1` can be removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `Scanner` instead of creating you own class,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = in.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    int var = in.nextInt();
    /* Do Something */
}
in.close();
```

Comment: scanner is slow....moreover replace my custom class with scanner wont solve the problem